# Graphing with matplotlib where one column has a particular value

Tags: csv, matplotlib, graph

I have a csv file with the following data.

```
Time,Type,RX,TX
2013-05-16 18:43:48,UP,0.72,10.86
2013-05-16 18:43:51,DOWN,68.74,1.67
2013-05-16 18:44:06,DOWN,104.01,2.52
2013-05-16 18:43:48,UP,1.21,10.94
2013-05-16 18:44:25,DOWN,104.07,2.54
```

I want two separate graphs:

- `RX` and `TX` graphed against time for `Type=UP`
- `RX` and `TX` graphed against time for `Type=DOWN`

Here is my attempt.  My problem is that both graphs contain all data.

```
plot = matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec(data_file)
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
subplot1 = matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(1,2,1)
subplot2 = matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(1,2,2)
subplot1.plot(plot.time, plot.rx)
subplot1.plot(plot.time, plot.tx)
subplot2.plot(plot.time, plot.rx)
subplot2.plot(plot.time, plot.tx)
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: using `plot` as a variable name is greatly confusing.  I don't quite understand your problem, you are telling it to plot all the data in both graphs, and it is doing so.  What have you tried to filter your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first filter your (poorly named) `plot` array into two separate arrays:

```
UP_data = plot[plot.type == 'UP']
DOWN_data = plot[plot.type == 'DOWN']
```

Then plot each separately:

```
subplot1.plot(UP_data.time, UP_data.rx)
subplot1.plot(UP_data.time, UP_data.tx)
subplot2.plot(DOWN_data.time, DOWN_data.rx)
subplot2.plot(DOWN_data.time, DOWN_data.tx)
```